# No component factory found for class{constructor(){this.iterablePlainMap=e.message}ngOnInit(){}}. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, typescript

**It working fine with `ng serve` but giving this error after `ng build ---prod`**

> This is is component class where i am creating dynamic component on run time
> **component.ts**

```
   dynamicComponent;
   dynamicModule: NgModuleFactory<any>;

   downloadFile() {
      this.http.get(this.fileUrl, { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(res => {
      this.dynamicComponent = this.createNewComponent(res);
      this.dynamicModule=this.compiler.compileModuleSync(this.createComponentModule(this.dynamicComponent));
    });
   }
```

**Create New Module function**

```
 protected createComponentModule(componentType: any) {
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        CommonModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        componentType,
      ],
      entryComponents: [componentType]
    })
    class RuntimeComponentModule {
    }
    // a module for just this Type
    return RuntimeComponentModule;
  }
```

**Create New Component Function**

```
 protected createNewComponent(text: string) {
    const that = this;
    @Component({
      selector: 'dynamic-component',
      template: `${text}`,
      interpolation: ['{[{', '}]}']
    })
    class DynamicComponent implements OnInit {
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    }
    return DynamicComponent;
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to acheive by creating a Module at runtime?

Comment: Yes first i am creating component and after that I am try to create a module at runtime